# Performance problems when generating animated gifs with gifshot

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

I've been using gifshot to try and generate large 79 frame animated gifs client side in a users browser.  It relates to a real time weather forecasting tool I built to help meteorology students get to grips with "real weather data".  My test example essentially produces an animated gif version of the data seen here on the live tool:

http://manunicast.seaes.manchester.ac.uk/view.php?t=20151001&d=d01&p=160,1,24&l=0,0,0#

This has three layers of images plus a background and foregrounds.  With the transparency set on the images, all the layering works well.

Whilst we offer single layer animated gifs generated server side, I want to allow users to create any combination of weather data they like which has mean client side gif generation.

gifshot seems pretty neat and works well for small examples, but I think I'm pushing things to the limit.  The following is the same weather data from the previous URL, but being processed to produce an animated gif client side.

WARNING: Selecting this link jumps straight into the process and gif generation takes around 90 seconds using Chrome and a fast desktop machine.  Viewing the console log will give an indication of progress.

http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/stuart.anderson/_prototypes/gifshot/gifshot-test.html

My current problem is that on some browsers, it just simply bombs out and won't complete.  On Chrome, it will complete, display, but then whilst the user is offered the option to "Same image as", nothing is ever downloaded from Chrome.  The image data which is pushed into the new window which displays the animated gif is all base64 encoded data as that is what you get back from gifshot.

The process starts with image caching and then proceeds to this script which does the real work:

javascript/build-customimage.js
(select this from from HTML source view)

I'm seeking input from anyone that may have attempted something similar.  How can I make the process more efficient?  Why does Chrome not allow the generated image to be downloaded when completed?  If I use less frames, it copes OK and it all works so I guess it must be memory related.  I feel I'm so near, yet so far from having a working solution.

Thanks in advance for any feedback or advice.

Comment: hi there almost a year gone - but I'm facing the same memory issue. Did you manage to resolve this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gifshot consumes a *huge* amount of memory. One of the biggest issues is it auto converts the images to base64, ballooning memory.

The brilliant Jimmy Warting (author of Stream Saver) wrote up a "stream" enabled version of GifWriter for me which I then used to download MUCH larger images. You can see our interaction here https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/issues/38

My code is open source - you can see how it was resolved [here](https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmNinja/blob/master/www/js/EventCtrl.js#L1356-L1442)

It's a little pointless posting code here - its a bit large but what Jimmy basically did for me is:

- Converted gif stream to support streams
- download images in chunks
- go directly to gifwriter instead of gifshot - the code I linked there can help